# ExtJS TreeStore update event fire instead of create

Tags: extjs4

I am using tree.Panel with TreeStore when I call

```
sel_node.parentNode.appendChild(node);
tree.getSampleStore().sync();
```

ExtJS fire event called sample store proxy: update url instead of create url what could I have done wrong?

Answer (score 3):

What exact version of ExtJS4 do you use?

In my situation, with ext-4.0.7-gpl, I debugged a bit a found out that `appendChild` method creates a node from and object and then performs some update operations concerning the node's position in the tree, like setting next sibling, parent etc., see [1].

When syncing, the store uses `getUpdatedRecords` and `getNewRecords` [2] methods to determine which operation to run. update or create. Somehow, our appended children turn out to be updated, not created.

Note that the method doesn't check whether the children of a parent node was loaded, just pushes the new node into an empty `childNodes` array; after all these operations end, other children of a parent node are never shown in the tree; and if the update operation caused the serverside generation of new `id`, the code breaks on the line `original = me.tree.getNodeById(record.getId());` - there is no such node with the old `id` generated on client side..

Simply put, I think it's a bug.

[1] http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/NodeInterface.html#Ext-data-NodeInterface-method-appendChild
[2] http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-0/source/AbstractStore.html#Ext-data-AbstractStore-method-getUpdatedRecords

**Add**: ExtJS 4.1 beta 2 doesn't work better for me

**Update with temp solution**: I hacked a bit and think I solved the issue by overriding the `appendChild` method of `NodeInterface` like below (just to set `phantom` property so that the record becomes created, not updated).

Please note:
1) You should include your `appendChild` call in the `NodeInterface` `expand` method callback, or the bug with pushing to the empty `childNodes` will remain: the new node will appear somewhere in the wrong place;
2) I had to override `updateIndexes` of the `AbstractView` as well, try not to do this and maybe you'll find out why;
3) there are some issues when the store tries to delete our newly created node the next time it syncs - couldn't trace it yet;
0) I am no way ExtJS or even JS guru, so feel free to correct this hack)

```
Ext.data.NodeInterface.oldGpv = Ext.data.NodeInterface.getPrototypeBody;
Ext.data.NodeInterface.getPrototypeBody = function(){
    var ret = Ext.data.NodeInterface.oldGpv.apply(this, arguments);

    ret.appendChild = function(node, suppressEvents, suppressNodeUpdate) {
        var me = this,
        i, ln,
        index,
        oldParent,
        ps;


        if (Ext.isArray(node)) {
            for (i = 0, ln = node.length; i < ln; i++) {
                me.appendChild(node[i]);
            }
        } else {
            node = me.createNode(node);

            if (suppressEvents !== true && me.fireEvent("beforeappend", me, node) === false) {
                return false;
            }

            index = me.childNodes.length;
            oldParent = node.parentNode;

            if (oldParent) {
                if (suppressEvents !== true && node.fireEvent("beforemove", node, oldParent, me, index) === false) {
                    return false;
                }
                oldParent.removeChild(node, null, false, true);
            }else{
                node.phantom = true;
            }

            if(me.isLoaded()){
                index = me.childNodes.length;
                if (index === 0) {
                    me.setFirstChild(node);
                }

                me.childNodes.push(node);
                node.parentNode = me;
                node.nextSibling = null;

                me.setLastChild(node);

                ps = me.childNodes[index - 1];
                if (ps) {
                    node.previousSibling = ps;
                    ps.nextSibling = node;
                    ps.updateInfo(suppressNodeUpdate);
                } else {
                    node.previousSibling = null;
                }
                node.updateInfo(suppressNodeUpdate);
            }

            //console.log('appendChild was called');

            // I don't know what this code mean even given the comment
            // in ExtJS native source, commented out

            // As soon as we append a child to this node, we are loaded
            //if (!me.isLoaded()) {
            //    me.set('loaded', true);
            //}

            // If this node didnt have any childnodes before, update myself
            //else 
            //if (me.childNodes.length === 1) {
            //    me.set('loaded', me.isLoaded());
            //}

            if (suppressEvents !== true) {
                me.fireEvent("append", me, node, index);

                if (oldParent) {
                    node.fireEvent("move", node, oldParent, me, index);
                }
            }

            return node;
        }
    };
    return ret;
};
```

this is my code to add a node by values taken from a form `domainForm`. The form opens by clicking an icon in an `actioncolumn` of our tree grid:

```
var node = grid.store.getAt(rowIndex);
node.expand(false, function(){
    var newDomain = domainForm.getValues();
    newDomain.parent = {id: node.raw.id}; // i don't know whether you'll need this
    var newNode = node.appendChild(newDomain);
    me.store.sync();
});
```

and `updateIndexes` overrider:

```
Ext.override(Ext.view.AbstractView, {
    updateIndexes : function(startIndex, endIndex) {
        var ns = this.all.elements,
            records = this.store.getRange(),
            i;

        startIndex = startIndex || 0;
        endIndex = endIndex || ((endIndex === 0) ? 0 : (ns.length < records.length?(ns.length - 1):records.length-1) );
        for(i = startIndex; i <= endIndex; i++){
            ns[i].viewIndex = i;
            ns[i].viewRecordId = records[i].internalId;
            if (!ns[i].boundView) {
                ns[i].boundView = this.id;
            }
        }
    }    
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Had the same issue, an update to ext-4.1.0-beta-2 fixed it.

Answer (score 0):

The reason might be wrong format of data that comes from the server in response to your request.
Syncronization doesn't happen. Pass 'success' key with the value of TRUE in the server response.

Answer (score 0):

Hmm ... try this ...

`beforeitemexpand(node, eOpts){
   if (node.data.expanded) return false
}`